# creating a simple pie chart

Tags: sql-server, xml, reporting-services, fetchxml

I need to create something like this in SSRS:

[image]

My source dataset is fetchxml. I have actually two datasets.

One dataset is just the datapoint **"347"** whereas the other datapoint is **"1000"**

```
Dataset_Active returns 347
Dataset_InActive returns 1000
```

I have the option of using these fields for the following 3 categories:

[image]

My issue is that I cannot use values from multiple datasets.

**How do I create a pie chart where the data comes from 2 different datasets? Also in the case that I just neeed to graph 2 values, should I use anything in the category/values/series or just use values?**

Comment: Have a look here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/53c5d2b1-36e4-4ef8-9bea-48adbf0475b4/multiple-datasets-in-a-single-chart It's saying the `Lookup` function gives you an option to get data from 2 datasets

Comment: thanks! where would i put that? in the cateogry groups or series groups or values? http://screencast.com/t/bL0dcpI0

Comment: Values I think but I'm not sure.